# How can I turn a list of assertions into a table? C#/Specflow Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#, browser-automation, specflow

I'm very new to using `C#/Specflow` to write tests. I have a test, that ends like this:

```
Then the Details page should display the rating zip code
    And the Details page should display the ID
    And the Details page should display the Eligible Employee count
```

And the code behind looks like this:

```
    [Then(@"the Details page should display the rating zip code")]
    public void ThenTheDetailsPageShouldDisplayTheRatingZipCode()

    {          
        string actualvalue = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.GroupInfoRow:nth-child(3) > label:nth-child(2)")).Text;
        Assert.IsTrue(actualvalue.Equals(actualvalue));          
    }

    [Then(@"the Details page should display the ID")]
    public void ThenTheDetailsPageShouldDisplayTheID()
    {
        string actualvalue = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.GroupInfoRow:nth-child(1) > label:nth-child(2)")).Text;
        Assert.IsTrue(actualvalue.Equals(actualvalue));
    }

    [Then(@"the Details page should display the Eligible Employee count")]
    public void ThenTheDetailsPageShouldDisplayTheEligibleEmployeeCount()
    {
        string actualvalue = Driver.Instance.FindElement(By.CssSelector("div.GroupInfoRow:nth-child(4) > label:nth-child(2)")).Text;
        Assert.IsTrue(actualvalue.Equals(actualvalue));
    }
```

I would rather it be displayed in a table format, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean with table format?

Comment: @NielsvanReijmersdal, I mean the following when I say table, a Specflow table (and my apologies this is not formatted properly when I save it): <p> Then the Details page should display the following:
 | field                       | value                              |
 | ZipCode                | <zipcode>                      |
 | ID                          | <ID>                               |
 | EligibleEmpCount | <EligEmpCount> |</p>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your specflow file should look like this:

```
Then the Details page should display the rating zip code
    And the Details page should display
    | Parameter       | Value |
    |  ID             | 5     |
    |  Employee Count | 125   |
```

And your code should look like this:

```
[Then(@"the Details page should display")]
public void DetailsPageShouldDisplay(Table table)
{
   List<TestParameter> detailsParameter = table.CreateSet<TestParameter>().ToList();
   // then iterate through detailsParameter by Name and do proper assertions
}
```

And your TestParameter class should look like this:

```
public class TestParameter
{
    [TableAliases("Parameter", "Field")]
    public string Name { get; set; } = "";

    public string Value { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using *Assert*, you can create your own Assert class (a singleton), where the method *IsXXX* call `Assert.IsXXX`, capture any possible Exception, save the message, and continue. In a `@AfterScenario`, you can call `Assert.IsTrue(false, singletonObject.message)` or do whatever you want with the Exceptions if you have any Exception capture there.

I am not a C# programmer, but the idea would be something like:

```
public void IsTrue(Boolean value, String message) { 
    try{
      Assert.IsTrue(value, message);
    } catch (AssertionError e) {
      this.HasFailed = true;
      this.ExceptionList.add(e); // or this.ExceptionList.add(e.message) or this.ExceptionList.add(message); 
    }
}
```